# Less installation failed with npm proxy error

Tags: less

i want to use less file, i find many tutorials in internet, and i have a bug with the installation of less. The command invit (Windows) do what you see in the picture. I try to config the proxy with command in stackoverflow similars questions but it's not works.
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRueu.png)

Comment: You should edit your question and insert the image in the post, not just external link. External links eventually become unavailable and so prevent prospect users with similar issue to benefit from your question. However I have not enough experience and can't help you. Hope someone else does though.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the address of registry. For example:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org
```

then enter

```
npm install less -g
```

Comment: I try many time, and it's finally works, thanks Lee Li for your help !